# Чтение RSS на PHP

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:yandex="http://news.yandex.ru" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>AAA</title>
    <link>AAA</link>
    <description>AAA</description>
    <yandex:logo>AAA</yandex:logo>
    <yandex:logo type="square">AAA</yandex:logo>
    <item>
        <title>AAA/title>
        <link>AAA</link>
        <pdalink>AAA</pdalink>
        <description>AAA</description>
        <author>AAA</author>
        <category>AAA</category>
        <enclosure url="AAA" type="image/jpeg"/>
        <pubDate>AAA</pubDate>
        <yandex:full-text>AAA</yandex:full-text>
    </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

Как получить из RSS url `<enclosure>` и содержимое `<yandex:full-text>` и вывести все данные в foreach?

Comment: Использовать SimpleXML, он уже встроен в PHP, ничего дополнительно подрубать не надо
http://www.webmasters.by/articles/web-programming/2778-parsing-xml-with-simplexml.html

Comment: Это не решило проблему. Обычные теги я могу вывести...к примеру title, а как получить url `<enclosure>` и содержимое `<yandex:full-text>` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# 1. Подключаем файлик.
$test = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
# 2. Получаем содержимое аттрибута url в enclosure
echo $test->channel->item->enclosure->attributes()->url;
# 3. Получаем содержимое yandex:full-text
$namespaces = $test->getNamespaces(true);
$dc = $test->channel->item->children($namespaces["yandex"]);
echo $dc;
```